# Aws ECR Jenkins Plugin Public Repo Support

Tags: jenkins, public, repo, amazon-ecr

Does AWS ECR Plugin for Jenkins Support to authenticate Public Repositories from AWS ECR?

Something Like this...

```
// Uploading Docker images into AWS ECR Public Repo
  stage('Pushing to ECR') {
    steps{  
      script {
        docker.withServer(
          'tcp://<Docker-Host>:2376', 
          'Docker_Server_Auth'
        ) 
        **{
          docker.withRegistry( 
            'https://public.ecr.aws/<alias>',
            'ecr-public:us-east-1:Aws_Credentials'
          )  
          {
            myImage.push("v13")
          }
        }**
      }    
    }
  }
```

The above pipeline code is failed to authenticate which throws error 'failed to authenticate'

With Private Repo Plugins works and Authenticates like below pipeline code

```
//Pushing to ECR Private Repo
stage('Pushing to ECR') {
  steps{
    script {
      docker.withServer(
        'tcp://<docker-host>:2376', 
        'Docker_Server_Auth'
        ) 
        **{
        docker.withRegistry( 
          'https://<acc-id>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
          'ecr:ap-south-1:Aws_Credentials'
        )  
        {
        myImage.push("v13")
        }
      }**
    }
  }
}
```

Using sh 'aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws/' works inside pipeline

Is there any way to authenticate ECR Public repo with ECR Plugin like we do with Private repo??